# How to use GraphicsEnvironment to detect display mirroring?

Tags: java

I use the following code to check how many screens are there and choose the biggest one to display my application. However I'm not yet successful in detecting cases when the displays are mirrored instead of extended. Is there any way how I can do that?

```
if (GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices().length > 1) {
    findBiggestScreen(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()).setFullScreenWindow(this);
} else {
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not test this because I don't have a second display available but maybe you can try [GraphicsDevice#getDefaultConfiguration()#getBounds()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html#getBounds%28%29).

It is not clearly mentioned in the javadoc but I guess that mirrored screens have equal values for x and y offset.